# Bibliography style MLA 8

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, mla-style

I am new to LaTex and writing my dissertation usingin Overleaf. I am using BibLaTex and MLA-style for bibliographical information. Now, MLA published their 8th style guide in April and I would like to know how to implement the changes. Or whether anyone has taken on the monumental task of updating the old MLA style-file? MLA 8 makes a lot more sense than MLA 7 to me and I think it will be as useful style guide.

In particular, I would like to know, how to get rid of the "print" and "web" info, and add commas between the information.

The 8th edition suggests e.g. the following style for journal entries:

Kincaid, Jamaica. “In History.” *Callaloo*, vol. 24, no. 2, Spring 2001, pp. 620-26.

Whereas the 7th edition had this here:

Kinkaid, Jamaica. “In History.” *Callaloo* 24.2 (Spring 2001): 620-26. Web.

(Examples from https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/22/)

Comment: If the changes are as big as you suggest, it will likely take some time for a complete overhaul. (Assuming someone is actually working on it.)

Comment: The present version can be patched with the help of `xpatch` package, if there are not too many patches  to apply.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It would be a lot of work to redefine every category for the entries with the xpatch package. It almost seems worth to tackle MLA8 instead. But since I have very little time left, maybe I should just go with APA or Chicago-style instead.

Comment: Unless you're forced to use MLA, I would just use APA, especially if you are writing in the natural or social sciences.  `biblatex-apa` is kept quite up-to-date.  But MLA and APA serve really different audiences and citing styles; if your field uses MLA generally, it might be simpler just to use `biblatex-mla` and not worry about 7th vs. 8th editions.

Comment: AFAIK `biblatex-mla` has not been updated for quite some time it has some problems with recent changes in `biblatex` and might not work properly any more. I would not want to go through `biblatex-mla` and change it from 7th to 8th edition. But writing a full MLA style is beyond the scope of a question on this site.

Comment: @Alan: as I am working between fields I could get away with APA. I will have to figure out with my supervisor. MLA 7 is just such a complete pain and defies common sense and I was hoping there was an easy workaround.

Comment: @moewe: I was not suggesting someone whip up an MLA 8 , just wondering if maybe someone knew if there is something in the works or if there was a clever workaround that I, as a newbie, wasn't aware of.

Comment: @PeaBee IMO MLA is a complete pain no matter what the edition. :)

Comment: @ Alan: You are probably right, but the 8th is half of the size of the 7th and there seems some logic to it. More than APA, it seems that Chicago style does what I have to do, and the file is kept up to date, so I'll play with that for now.

Comment: I've just uploaded to GitHub a beta with the 8th-edition changes. You can see the update here: http://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla

Answer (score 2):

The [`biblatex-mla`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla) maintainer has updated the package to properly work with recent versions of `biblatex`. The style now includes `mla-new` that implements the 8th edition of the MLA style guide. See also the [`CHANGES` file on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-mla/CHANGES)